# Symfony 2.8 Guard AbstractGuardAuthenticator, how to return a real token?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I'm playing around with `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` from the relatively new `Guard` subsystem added in Symfony 2.8.

My setup is really simple. I send a request to a protected URL which takes a username:password base64 encoded. It checks both against the database and should return a token.

The authentication successful method:

```
 public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        //If login successful, return token
        return new Response($this->tokenStorage->getToken());        
    }
```

What it returns is:

```
 PostAuthenticationGuardToken(user="test", authenticated=true, roles="ROLE_ADVANCED,
 ROLE_USER")
```

Now, this is what I'd expect given that the `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` defines the method for creating this token exactly like this.

```
public function createAuthenticatedToken(UserInterface $user, $providerKey)
    {
        return new PostAuthenticationGuardToken(
            $user,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }
```

UPDATE 1.1:

Using the `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` I am now attempting to implement Json Web Tokens into my application's [AbstractGuardAuthenticator](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Guard/AbstractGuardAuthenticator.html). The Lexik bundle provides both a success and failure handler: `lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success` & `lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure` which point at classes that get certain JWT variables injected into them. How do I hook them into `AbstractGuardAuthenticator`'s success and failure handlers?

```
 crud:
         anonymous: ~
         guard:
             authenticators:
                - app.token_authenticator
         pattern: ^/database/
```

And the `Guard` success and failure methods

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    if ($token = $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN')) {
        //on success, let the request continue
    } else {
        //If login successful, return token
        return new Response($this->tokenStorage->getToken());
    }
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $data = array(
        'message' => strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData())

        // or to translate this message
        // $this->translator->trans($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData())
    );

    return new JsonResponse($data, 403);
}
```

I am currently extending and merging `JWTTokenAuthenticator` with my own token authenticator instead of the `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` as both implement `GuardAuthenticatorInterface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to know how to return a real token, which can be used to authenticate a user instead of sending the username:password every time.

**Symfony Guard Component**

*Guard aims at simplifying the authentication subsystem.*

Before Guard, setting up custom authentication was a lot more work. You needed to create several parts/classes and make them work together. It's flexible, you can create any authentication system you want, but it needs some effort. With Guard, it becomes a lot easier, while maintaining all flexibility.

This is *not* the component you're looking for.

**Symfony Security Token**

When reading the word "token" in documentation about the Guard Component, what's referred to is an implementation of the [TokenInterface](https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/2.8/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.php). Symfony uses these implementations to keep track of the authentication state. These implementations never leave your application, it's an internal thing.

This is *not* the token you're looking for.

**JSON Web Token**

The "token" you're talking about is some pease of information a client can use to authenticate with. This can be a random string like the "access token" of [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) protocol, or a self-contained and signed set of information, like [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io) (JWT).

IMHO JWT would be the most future-proof token at the moment. [The Anatomy of a JSON Web Token](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token) is a good read to get familiar with JWT.

There are several bundles out there that can easily integrate JWT into your Symfony project. [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) is the most popular one right now. I suggest you have a look :)

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I am going to read into it now and I'll get back to you asap. Since the `GuardTokenInterface` only implements the `TokenInterface` I was pretty confused on what to do with them.

Comment: I've been messing around with the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle for a while now and I think I have most of it working now, but I'm confused on how to implement this in the my `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` as the documentation suggests injecting these authentication handlers via a `form_login` which I don't use. I'll update my question with the configuration details.